# Wireless router won't let a specific computer reconnect unless its power cycled

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I provide tech support for an elderly gentleman who is very tech illiterate. I set him up with a laptop connected to his TV, and literally the only thing he does with it is check email from the family (a tablet screen is too small and his hands are shaky in case you're wondering why I don't just hook him up with an iPad or something).

I have set up a non-admin account to autologon and I've installed Firefox in kiosk mode so it just goes straight to his email. I've also disabled sleep and automatic updates and set a reboot task every night because he never turns it off. I've also installed TeamViewer on it so his adult children can remote in when they need to.

This machine's configuration has not changed at all in the 18+ months since I installed it.

He started complaining recently that he could not access the Internet at all, and his daughter called me in to help. When I came over, I noticed that his computer would not connect to the router, even after rebooting it. So I just power cycled the router and everything was working again. I left it running updates since it was over a year behind and told him I would remote in later on to check its progress.

I wound up having to go back over because he lost Internet access again. Same thing as before, Windows would not connect to the router. This time I paid attention to it before resetting it. All the lights were normal and I could connect with my phone. But Windows could not even after a reboot. So I power cycled the router again, and Windows picked it right up without needing to even reboot the computer.

So what would cause this? Clearly the configuration on the computer is good because it picks the router right up after I power cycle it -- no reboot required. This is the only computer that I can say with 100% certainty that has not changed one iota since the day I installed it.

And clearly the router is good because I can connect to it with my phone.

But as I sit here writing this, his computer will not connect for the third time, and I am writing this on my phone over the same WiFi.

I've already tried running a virus scan and updating the driver. The computer was clean and only time will tell if the drive fixed it. But I don't see how the driver or firmware could be causing it because as I said, this computer has not changed at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I was having a very similar problem for several days many moons back. Some Windows-based computers would fail to connect/reconnect to my wireless router every few hours until the router was power-cycled. A friend suggested replacing the power adapter. It turned out he was right; the router has been running great since I replaced the power adapter. I just had to make sure the replacement had identical output voltage, equal or higher output current, and same polarity and connector as the original one.